# How do i Extract tooltip content using selenium where tooltip is dynamically loading by javascript?

Tags: javascript, selenium, python-2.7, tooltip

I am testing a web-application where i need to verify the contents of a tooltip that is displayed on moving my mouse over a part of the graphics.

Here is the section of html code where this tip is coming from:

```
<div id="area-serverSlot-6a" class="annotation" style="width: 21px; height: 38px; left: 186px; top: 117px; position: absolute; z-index: 20; cursor: pointer;" name="annotation" present="1" tooltip="" href="javascript:select_module('server', '6a');" onareaover="javascript:DisplayTip('serverSlot-6a', TITLE,'Server Slot 6a')" onareaout="javascript:UnTip()"></div>
```

I am not able to move my mouse on top of the tooltip as it moves with the mouse.
Please suggest some way to get the contents of the tooltip.

Here is the code for DisplayTip:

```
function DisplayTip()
{
var titleType = arguments[2];
var slotNumPos = titleType.lastIndexOf(' ');
var slotNum = " UNKNOWN";
var title = "UNKNOWN";
if (titleType.indexOf('Server') >= 0) title = vServerSlot;
else if (titleType.indexOf('IOM') >= 0) title = vIOMSlot;
else if (titleType.indexOf('PSU') >= 0) title = vPSUSlot;
else if (titleType.indexOf('CMC') >= 0) title = vCMCSlot;
else  if (titleType.indexOf('KVM') >= 0) title = vKVMSlot;
else if (titleType.indexOf('Fan') >= 0) title = vFanSlot;
else if (titleType.indexOf('LCD') >= 0) title = vLcdSlot;
if (slotNumPos >= 0)
{
slotNum = titleType.substring(slotNumPos);
title += slotNum;
}
TagToTip(arguments[0], TITLE, title, JUMPHORZ, true,
JUMPVERT, true, ABOVE, true);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the JS for `DisplayTip()` ?

Comment: Hey @PatMeeker , i have included the code for DisplayTip above.

Answer (score 1):

Nick,

I have taken an example of Linkedin.

```
 WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.linkedin.com/");
    WebElement onElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/h2/a"));
    System.out.println("Tooltip : " + onElement.getAttribute("title"));
```

Comment: Hey Adi, There is no title attribute as shown in the above code snippet. If title would have been present, i could have easily used getattribute.

Comment: You have attribute title in your code (TITLE,'Server Slot 6a')

Comment: Adi, that TITLE is a parameter to the java-script function and not an attribute of html code. How do i read this TITLE ?

Comment: Nick, when you manually hover over the element are you seeing a tooltip displayed? Even if the original html document doesn't contain the `title` attribute for that element - still, after the JavaScript adds it, it should become present in the "computed source." So if you are seeing the tooltip displayed, Selenium's `getAttribute("title")` should still return the info you're looking for after that point.